# No matching function for call to getline(std::istream&, int&)

Tags: c++, string, getline

I was writing a code which task statements as inputs from user and searches for the word "not" being present in it or not
if not is present then it prints *Real Fancy* else it prints *regularly fancy* but i am getting an error in such a simple program.

My Code looks like :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    string str2 (" not ");
    string str3 ("not ");
    string str4 ("not");

    int T;
    std::getline(std::cin, T);
    for (int k=0;k<T;k++){
        string str ;


        std::getline(std::cin, str);
        int len = str.size();
        //condition for only not as a sentence
        if ((str.find(str4) != string::npos) && len ==3) {
            cout<<"Real Fancy";
        }        
        // condition to check for not word in middle of a sentence eg. this is not good
        else if ((str.find(str2) != string::npos) ) {
            cout<<"Real Fancy";
        }        
        // condition if the statement ends with the word not 
        else if (str[len-1]=='t' && str[len-2]== 'o' && str[len-3]== 'n' && str[len-4]== ' '){
            cout<<"Real Fancy";
        }        
        // code to check for if statement starts with word not
        else if ((str.find(str3) != string::npos) ) {
            cout<<"Real Fancy";
        }
        else {
            cout<<"regularly fancy";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and the error i am getting once i run this code is :

> main.cpp:11:30: error: no matching function for call to ‘getline(std::istream&, int&)’

Comment: You can improve your question with little effort: Just remove the entire `for` loop. Without it you get the same compiler error message. Keep in mind that a *minimum*, working example is preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::getline()` function is not for integer type.
If you want to use `std::getline()` for your integer, you should declare temporary string type value.
for example in your case

```
int T;
std::string tmp_s;
std::getline(std::cin, tmp_s);
T = std::stoi(tmp_s);
```

Answer (score 2):

[`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) has two overloads:

```cpp
(1) istream& getline (istream& is, string& str, char delim);
(2) istream& getline (istream& is, string& str);
```

You are trying to call it with an `int` parameter, which won't work.

There are two ways to solve this:

Use [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to parse the `int` after reading into a `std::string`

Read from the stream directly into an `int` by using `std::cin >> T`. This will not consider new lines specially though and use any whitespace as a separator between ints. So if you are trying to parse exactly one `int` per line, the former option will suit your better.

Comment: Why should `std::cin >> T` not consider line limits? New line is also a whitespace. Probably just a matter of wording.

Comment: What I meant is that it uses any whitespace as a separator, including newlines. It looks like OP wants to specifically parse one int per line, which stream operators don't take into account.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) has the following overloads:

```cpp
istream& getline (istream&  is, string& str, char delim);
istream& getline (istream&& is, string& str, char delim);
istream& getline (istream&  is, string& str);
istream& getline (istream&& is, string& str);
```

and, as you can see, none of them receives integer as a second parameter, so here are possible solutions for you:

- if you are limited to C++11, use [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) in a following manner:

```cpp
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
int T = std::stoi(line);
```

- if you are able to use C++17, I would strongly recommend you to use [`std::from_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) as follows:

```cpp
int value = 0;
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
const auto result = std::from_chars(str.data(), str.data() + str.size(), value);
if (result.ec == std::errc()) {
    // strings is successfully parsed
}
```

**Why is `std::from_chars` better than `std::stoi`?**

Because `std::from_chars` is non-throwing and gives you better error reporting (which will give you more info about the conversion outcome). Also, it is a bit faster than `std::stoi` according to some resources. Read more about `std::from_chars` [here](https://www.bfilipek.com/2018/12/fromchars.html).

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

You should be looking to use getline in this form:

```
istream& getline (istream&  is, string& str); 
istream& getline (istream&& is, string& str);
```

You do this:

```
int T;
std::getline(std::cin, T);
```

`T` is an integer and there is no such call that can be made.

Comment: thanx a lot for all your contributions and i got where i went wrong. Will give a try right now with the solutions provided and hit back as soon as possible